# A single rewriterule matches 2 different cases

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have below 2 urls to redirect,

```
example.host.com/index.php
host.com/example/index.php
```

when the server is under maintenance, I would like to redirect them to:

```
example.host.com/maintenance.php
host.com/example/maintenance.php
```

with help of .htaccess

I know how to achieve them separately, but now I would want a single writerule to do the job for me.

Below is what I wrote in .htaccess, but not work as expected.

```
Options FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)/([^/]+)/?$ $1/maintenance.php [R=307,L]
```

Any help or idea why it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this single rule:

```
Options FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# generate dynamic rewrite base var
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(.*?/)(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteRule !maintenance\.php$ %{ENV:BASE}maintenance.php [R=307,L,NC]
```

Comment: wow, just copied and tried, worked like a charm. but would you mind explaining a little about the rewrite condition and rules?

Comment: Yes only first rule to get dynamic RewriteBase is a bit tricky. That rule is capturing current URI (relative to the directory of .htaccess) in `$1`. And in `RewriteCond` it combines it with `%{REQUEST_URI}::`. (Note that `%{REQUEST_URI}` is always the full path from DocumentRoot). Then on RHS it uses a backreference variable `\2` to capture different between `%{REQUEST_URI}` and `$1` in a separate variable `%1` and that is set to Env variable `BASE`.

Comment: I'm trying to understand it. At the same time, I added 
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1\.2\.3\.4
to exclude myself from seeing the maintenance page. But the url becomes some {hostname}.{filepath}. Should not it stop rewrite when I exclude myself?

Comment: Sure you can add `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1\.2\.3\.4` before 2nd `RewriteRule` line above. Bit make sure your public IP is correctly seen by Apache.